# Big-O: If ${f(n)}=O(g(n))$, prove/disprove ${(f(n))^3} = O (g(n))^3 )$

Tags: asymptotics

I have to prove or disprove this:
If ${f(n)}=O(g(n))$, prove/disprove ${(f(n))^3} = O (g(n))^3 )$.
From what we are given:  ${f(n)}<=C_1g(n)$ for some constant $C_1$.
Now I have to show that ${(f(n))^3} <= C_2(g(n))^3 )$. My intuition says that we should be able to find a constant $C_2$ and that $C_2 = C_1^3$. Is this wrong? If wrong, what would be the right way to think about it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know - is $f(n)$ non negative?

Comment: no, can be negative or positive

Comment: Then there from definition should be $|f| \leqslant C |g|$ and your suggestion about $C^3$ is correct conclusion.